# KineticJs one image with multi stroke

Tags: canvas, kineticjs, stroke

I know how to apply a stroke in one image.

Is it possible use multi-stroke in one image?

Maybe like this results.
[image]

Or how could I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is just draw several `Kinetic.Rect` nodes on top of your image with required stroke AND transparent background (you can skip `fill` property or set it to `rgba(0,0,0,0)`).

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 0, y: 0,
  width: 100, height: 50,
  stroke: 'red'
})
```

Comment: I will try your suggest
Thansks